# asp.net display image from byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, linq

I have a byte array and trying to display image from that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Linq;

namespace RealPortableTerminal
{
public partial class resim : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PortableTerminalDbEntities entity = new PortableTerminalDbEntities();
        byte[] arr = (from b in entity.Sicil where b.Id == 31 select b.Fotograf).First();

        Image rImage = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arr))
        {
            rImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
}
}
```

It underlines FromStream and says 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromStream'. It seems adding System.Data.Linq reference did not changed anything. Am I missing something ? Btw I am pretty sure I take byte array from database correctly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Another way to do it is to convert your byte array into a base 64 string and assign that to the `ImageUrl` property of `rImage`, like so:

```
rImage.ImageUrl = "data:image;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(arr);
```

You don't need the intermediate `MemoryStream` or a separate page...if the byte array is in an image format the browser supports, it will display.  Good luck.

Answer (score 11):

```
<img id="img" runat="server" alt=""/>
```

In code behind

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(arr, 0, arr.Length);
img.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
```

You wouldn't need `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably thinking of `System.Drawing.Image`; that class supports `FromStream`.

[This forum post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1131426.aspx?Displaying+a+System+Drawing+Image+on+web+page) shows you a few ways to load dynamic images in WebForms.

Probably the simplest way would be to create a separate aspx page which loads your image as you're doing here and use `Response.BinaryWrite` to save it to the response stream, then in the page you're working on, create an `Image` control which uses the new aspx page as its image URL. You can of course use query string parameters if you need to load a variety of images.

Comment: You shouldn't use an ASPX page for that. Those are for Web Forms pages, and it's hacky to use them for this sort of thing. You can write a handler, or a generic handler (.ashx) for this purpose.