# Easy way to retrieve image source in abp

Tags: asp.net-core, abp

I'm pretty new to ABP Framework and probably this question has a really simple answer, but I haven't managed to find it. Images are an important part of any app and handling them the best way (size, caching) is mandatory.

**Scenario**

- setup a File System Blob Storing provider. This means that the upload file will be stored in the file system as an image file
- make a service that uses a Blob container to save and retrieve the image. So, after saving it, I use the unique file name as a blob name. This name is used to retrieve it back.
- the user is logged in, so authorization is required
- I can easily obtain the `byte[]`s of the image by calling `blobContainer.GetAllBytesOrNullAsync(blobName)`
- I want to easily display the image in `<img>` or in `datatable` row directly.

So, here is my question: is there an easy way to use a blob stored image as `src` of a `<img>` directly in a razor page? What I've managed to achieve is setting in the model, a source as a string made from `image type + bytes converted to base 64 string` (as [here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39338704/379865) however in this case I need to do it in the model and also I don't know if caching is used by the browser. I don't see how caching would work in this case.

I am aware that this may be a question more related to asp.net core, but I was thinking that maybe in abp there is some way via a link to access the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the ID of the blob then it is easy to do. Just create a Endpoint to get the Image based on the blob id.

Here is the sample AppService

```cs
public class DocumentAppService : FileUploadAppService
{
    private readonly IBlobContainer<DocumentContainer> _blobContainer;
    private readonly IRepository<Document, Guid> _repository;
    public DocumentAppService(IRepository<Document, Guid> repository, IBlobContainer<DocumentContainer> blobContainer)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _blobContainer = blobContainer;
    }

    public async Task<List<DocumentDto>> Upload([FromForm] List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        var output = new List<DocumentDto>();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var id = Guid.NewGuid();
            var newFile = new Document(id, file.Length, file.ContentType, CurrentTenant.Id);
            var created = await _repository.InsertAsync(newFile);
            await _blobContainer.SaveAsync(id.ToString(), memoryStream.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
            output.Add(ObjectMapper.Map<Document, DocumentDto>(newFile));
        }

        return output;
    }

    public async Task<FileResult> Get(Guid id)
    {
        var currentFile = _repository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (currentFile != null)
        {
            var myfile = await _blobContainer.GetAllBytesOrNullAsync(id.ToString());
            return new FileContentResult(myfile, currentFile.MimeType);
        }

        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Upload function will `upload` the files and `Get` function will get the file.

Now set the Get route as a `src` for the image.

Here is the blog post: https://blog.antosubash.com/posts/dotnet-file-upload-with-abp

Repo: https://github.com/antosubash/FileUpload

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You are saying that I can use the app service directly in the src of the image, so have something like `https://localhost:port/api/ducument/blobId` without anything else needed, like maybe `Html.Action`? That would be pretty cool. I'll give it a try. Does this way of retrieving the image allow caching by the browser on second request?

Comment: yes. That is what i'm doing.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: @AntoSubash Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77079052/abp-io-get-azure-blob-url . The above solution in my case could result in multiple API calls 1. Get the Image API Url. 2. The Image API URL will be src of a Img tag. 3. Again this will invoke another API call to get actual image content.