# Full Blob URL isn't returned

Tags: azure-blob-storage, abp

We are following [BLOB Storing Azure Provider](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Blob-Storing-Azure) and were able to upload the files to Azure Blob Storage as given below.

```
await _blobContainer.SaveAsync(filename, input.ResourceFile.OpenReadStream(), true);
```

But this doesn't return the full Blob URL.

We upload tenant logo and we would like to capture the URL and save it to DB Column. This URL will be part of the API response whenever the Tenant Details API is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option for you is to use the tenant ID as Blob file name. then you can retrive the logo with tenant ID.

ABP blob storing system is used to store and retrive the blob. you have to do everything else.

I usally use it like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70595148/1068147

For logo I use Tenant Id and for profile picture I use userId